# What happens if my ESTA expires on the day of arrival?

Tags: usa, esta

I'm French and will travel the 14th of June to the US. My ESTA expires the 14th of  June 2013 and I'm wondering if my ESTA will be valid when I'll land in the US on the 14th of June 2013.

Does someone know anything about that?

Comment: While technically it's valid, why would you want to take a chance on CBP agent who might interpret it differently and wend you through the ringer because he doesn't want to take a chance on being wrong

Answer (score 9):

You have an edge case. Typically, it is OK for the ESTA to expire during your visit. From [US Customs and Border Protection website](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1223/~/does-my-esta-need-to-be-valid-for-my-entire-stay-in-the-united-states%3F):

> **Does my ESTA need to be valid for my entire stay in the United States?**
>
> No, An ESTA is only required to be valid on the day you enter the
>   United States. The ESTA does not need to be valid for the entire time
>   a traveler is in the U.S.. If the ESTA expires while you are in the
>   U.S., it will not affect your admissibility or the amount of time you
>   are permitted to remain in the U.S. If an ESTA travel authorization
>   expires before the traveler leaves the United States, the traveler is
>   not required to apply for another. The traveler will need to apply for
>   a new travel authorization through ESTA, however, for future travel.

You should either contact the nearest USA consulate and get a definitive on if it is considered valid for the day of expiration or not or, as most ESTA applications are approved within minutes, you could simply renew your ESTA. An ESTA may be renewed prior to the previous one expiring.

On the renewal front a little Googling turned up:

> Please plan to apply at least 72 hours before you travel to allow time
>   for ESTA processing.

On [UsaEmbassy.gov](http://japan.usembassy.gov/e/visa/tvisa-estageneralfaq.html). That is 3 days, so you are just about on the right side of the equation, depending on when your flight is. Most likely, since you already had an ESTA, you'll be approved automatically in minutes.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same situation and contacted the authorities and they replied by saying the ESTA is valid until the end of the day of the expiration date. So you can travel on the day of your ESTA expiry:

"Yes, the ESTA would be valid through 11:59 PM on its expiration date. You can use the ESTA if it will be valid for your date of travel and date of arrival. Note that if your travel or processing through immigration is delayed that this could cause problems if your ESTA will become expired during the delay. We hope this helps to answer your question."