# ESTA Expiration to the day

Tags: esta

Our two-year ESTA will expire on the plane journey home to Australia. Will this be considered OK at point of entry?

Comment: Related - [What happens if my ESTA expires on the day of arrival?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/what-happens-if-my-esta-expires-on-the-day-of-arrival?rq=1)

Comment: I'm guessing she means that she is travelling to the US, but her return flight is on the expiry date of the ESTA.  Would that cause problems with immigration at the US border on arrival?